# How to apply a fill to a shape without losing the individual paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

In the image I have a black 1/4-circle and two wavy lines. Is there a way I can apply a fill to the space between the two wavy lines without selecting all the shapes and using the pathfinder tools to cut up the 1/4-circle?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using LIVE PAINT. If you're not familiar with that then it's well worth having a hunt for a tutorial. There's lots to explore and a few little quirks that can trip you up when you're new to it.

Is this case, you just need to follow these steps:

1. Select all of the items in your design that are involved and go to `Object > Live Paint > Make` (alt-command-x)
2. Select the Live Paint Bucket tool (K), change the colour to the colour that you want to fill the shape with and click anywhere in the area that you want to fill

That's it. The area will fill with the desired colour and will magically update if you move any of the elements.

*A brief word of warning: this is one of those features that is great for designers, but can cause problems when saving files out for sharing or printing so expanding the appearance (or rasterising) of these objects may well be required when your design is complete, before releasing it into the wild.*